# How to remove a domain controller from the domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, window-server-2012

I'm trying to delete a domain controller server that hasn't existed in a decade (the server itself is long dead).

I tried to delete the machine from the list of **Domain Controllers** by deleting the machine from the **Domain Controllers** node in **Active Directory Users and Computers**:

[image]

But it gives an error:

[image]

Of course it's not operational.

So now what?

## netdom.exe

> Does **`netdom query fsmo`** show good owners for each role?

```
>netdom query fsmo
Schema master               dc2.serverfault.com
Domain naming master        epstein.serverfault.com
PDC                         dc3.serverfault.com
RID pool manager            dc3.serverfault.com
Infrastructure master       dc3.serverfault.com
```

## Active Directory Sites and Services (dssite.msc)

Trying to delete the server using **Active Directory Sites and Services** (`dssite.msc`) gives the error saying **don't** do it:

> ### Active Directory Domain Services
>
> Do not delete the EPSTEIN container object. EPSTEIN contains objects representing Domain Controller EPSTEIN and possibly other DCs. To delete these objects, demote the DCs using the Active Directory Domain Services Installation Wizard (DCPROMO). ***If the DCs represented by these objects are permanently offline and can no longer be demoted using the Active Directory Domain Services Installation Wizard (DCPROMO), you must delete them one at a time.***

*(emphasis mine)*

Of course it doesn't say **what** to delete one at a time, **where** to delete it, or **how** to delete it.

## Active Directory Domains and Trusts

Trying to use **Active Directory Domains and Trusts** tool:

- right click the **Active Directory Domains and Trusts [ dc3.serverfault.com ]** node
- click **Operations Manager**

And you are presented with a dialog:

> The domain naming operations master ensures that domain names are unique. Only one Active Directory Domain Controller in the enterprise performs this role.
>
> Domain naming operations master:
> `epstein.serverfault.com`
>
> To transfer the domain naming master role to the following computer, click Change.
> `dc3.serverfault.com`

[image]

> The transfer of the operations master role cannot be performed because:
> The requested FSMO operation failed. The current FSMO holder could not be contacted.

I didn't ask you if you could contact it; i told you to fix it!

I just **love** this cargo-cult randomly-try-things approach. It's much better than Microsoft having a user-interface that does it. Or documentation.

## Bonus Reading

- Microsoft TechCommunity: [Step-By-Step: Manually Removing A Domain Controller Server](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/step-by-step-manually-removing-a-domain-controller-server/ba-p/280564)
- [How to properly and completely remove a Windows domain controller?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1088120/how-to-properly-and-completely-remove-a-windows-domain-controller)
- [How to remove orphaned Domain Controller's DNS records?](https://serverfault.com/questions/595419/how-to-remove-orphaned-domain-controllers-dns-records)
- [Domain controller failed on domain, how do I remove it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/871110/domain-controller-failed-on-domain-how-do-i-remove-it)
- [Domain Controller etiquette after a crash between Server 2003 & Server 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/869700/domain-controller-etiquette-after-a-crash-between-server-2003-server-2008)
- [How to demote a Domain Controller (DC) in Windows Server 2012 Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS)](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/how-to-demote-a-domain-controller-dc-in-windows-server-2012-active-directory-domain-services-ad-ds/)

Comment: Does `netdom query fsmo` show good owners for each role? Does using dssite.msc to delete the NTDS Settings object of the DC produce the same error?

Comment: @GregAskew It shows the server that doesn't exist is the *Domain naming master*

Comment: I think you will need to seize that role. Haven't experienced this in a while to know if that is causing the attempted network connection.